# background positioning using repeat-y

Tags: css, background-image

I have a background image, that is simply a wrapper for the main content of my page.

I have set this image a background image like:

```
#background {
    background: url("../image/bg.png") repeat-y 133px 50px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I would have thought that this would position the image 133px from the left and 50px from the top, but it is flush against the top of the browser.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is doing this?

Thanks

Can this kind of position be done when the image has `repeat-y`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `repeat-y` so the background is repeated vertically, **both down and up**. The value you specified - `50px` - is the place where the original background starts, but if your background has a height of 50px, you will not notice the difference as it is repeated above it as well.

Comment: Would you adivse on doing something different? Possibly using negative margins?

Comment: @terrid25 There are probably several possibilities depending on what you are trying to achieve. One would be to give your `body` a top margin of 50px and put the image in there and give your `#background` a negative top margin of 50px.

Comment: I'm trying to achive the following: I have a main div named container, which at the moment is centrally aligned. I then have a wrapper div around this, which is to be the background image, which is like a drop shadow effect on either side of the container. This background wrapper, needs to start about 50px from up the container. Thus my initial example of trying to vertically position using the repeat-y. I have tried using negative margins with no success.

Comment: @terrid25 I´d probably look for a cleaner solution depending on the design, but a fast fix is a container between `#background` and `#container` that has an x-repeating, 50px height, background-color background.